# Wicket: How to create a re-usable footer component section?

Tags: components, wicket

How do I create a component (like a footer section) and include it on a page?

I read stuff like markup inheritance, but that doesnt sound right (how would you re-use a footer section component in different pages when it can only inherit from a single page).

This is my 2nd day of using Wicket and wicket-library.com has some great examples, but at the moment it seems to be down when you try to view the source.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Create a basepage with header, footer, menu etc. Then extend you pages from that page. Use it like this:

```
public class BasePage extends WebPage {
    public BasePage() { 
        add(new HeaderPanel("header"), 
            new FooterPanel("footer"), 
            new MenuPanel  ("menu"  ));
    }
}
```

With this html:

```
<html xmlns:wicket>
<body>
    <div wicket:id="header">
    <div wicket:id="menu">
    <wicket:child></wicket:child>
    <div wicket:id="footer">
</body>
</html>
```

You would need to create a HeaderPanel, FooterPanel and MenuPanel.

Your child page example:

```
public class MyPage extends BasePage { ...}
```

Which has this html:

```
<html xmlns:wicket>
<body>
    <wicket:extend>
    </wicket:extend>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also create a no-menu basepage etc. The components and html you add to your child page will be placed between the  tags of the basepage.